# How to get a file to delete if it exists

Tags: php

I am trying to check if the instance of a filename exists (despite it's extension) and then delete it.  Here is what I have that is not working...

```
$username  = $_POST["data"]["username"];

$mask = '../../files/' . $username . '.*';
if (file_exists($mask)) 
{
unlink ($mask);
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I know that the first line is correct because it is being used correctly with other commands.  Just not sure about the rest.  Using PHP 5.2

Comment: It would be wise to sanitise `$username` first; `basename($username)` would be a start to get rid of directory separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$mask = "../../files/".str_replace("/","",$username).".*";
$glob = glob($mask);
if( $glob && count($glob) == 1) {
    unlink($glob[0]);
}
```

This starts by making your code just a little safer, so a malicious user can't just go around deleting anything they like. It also refuses to delete stuff if there's more than one file matching. Adjust as needed.

However, a malicious user can still use your code to delete... well, *anyone's* profile. Might want to guard against that properly ;)

Comment: **Note:** If glob return `false` it is still countable and matches with `1` so its better to use `empty`

Comment: It would be nice if the `str_replace()` also tackles Windows directory separators.

Comment: @user2284703 It's to prevent someone from entering a username like `../../../etc/whatever`.

Comment: oh... no worries there...  you see people don't actually access the page.  it's an unknown page that is being accessed via ajax whereas the url is not really passed in a variable on the url either.  Then add in the factor that much of the code is encrypted serverside..

By the way.. I'm an idiot... It DID work... I was just uploading it to test server2  and looking at the results on test server1.  Jeesh... I need sleep.

Comment: Just because it's hidden, does *not* mean it's safe. If it's reachable *anywhere at all*, then a malicious user can abuse it.